# How to use django-debug-toolbar for django-tastypie?

Tags: django, debugging, tastypie

django-debug-toolbar needs its output to be html, but django-tastypie's default output format is json.

I tried sending `http://localhost/api/v1/resource/?format=html` but it says `Sorry, not implemented yet. Please append "?format=json" to your URL`

Even though this doc lists html as one of valid option, it says its on the `TODO list`.
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serialization.html#to-html

How do I use debug toolbar to debug tastypie api calls?
(eg, I'd like to see how many sql queries are being run for api calls.. and so on)

Maybe I can call the api from django views but how?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is a middleware I wrote for similar purposes that wraps json in HTML for enabling the debug toolbar and also pretty prints it. Furthermore, it supports binary data. I'm not using tastypie, but I think it should work with that too.

```
# settings-dev.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json   

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'NonHtmlDebugToolbarMiddleware',
)

class NonHtmlDebugToolbarMiddleware(object):
    """
    The Django Debug Toolbar usually only works for views that return HTML.
    This middleware wraps any non-HTML response in HTML if the request
    has a 'debug' query parameter (e.g. http://localhost/foo?debug)
    Special handling for json (pretty printing) and
    binary data (only show data length)
    """

    @staticmethod
    def process_response(request, response):
        if request.GET.get('debug') == '':
            if response['Content-Type'] == 'application/octet-stream':
                new_content = '<html><body>Binary Data, ' \
                    'Length: {}</body></html>'.format(len(response.content))
                response = HttpResponse(new_content)
            elif response['Content-Type'] != 'text/html':
                content = response.content
                try:
                    json_ = json.loads(content)
                    content = json.dumps(json_, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                response = HttpResponse('<html><body><pre>{}'
                                        '</pre></body></html>'.format(content))

        return response
```

Comment: Minor fix: this did not work for me as answered for Django 1.7. I had to make a change to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES include: instead of 'NonHtmlDebugToolbarMiddleware' I had to specify 'myapp.settings.NonHtmlDebugToolbarMiddleware'. Other than that - awesome!

Comment: @karan it works perfectly fine with django rest API, but when I used it with swagger it shows 0 number of queries in sql panel, even though I ran some queries. Can you please suggest some thing ?

Comment: This will break the toolbar panels on the current version of django-debug-toolbar because it tries to parse the response from its own endpoint as JSON. I modified this to allow `'application/json'` responses to pass through without modification in order for it to work on the current package version.

Answer (score 8):

The Django Debug Toolbar's middleware actually has code in it to prevent it being activated for non-html type responses like those returned by TastyPie. What I have done in the past is create a bit of middleware that converts json responses into HTML so the toolbar will be activated and I can count queries etc... It is a bit of a hack but it gets to job done and is easy to turn on/off.

```
from django.conf import settings


class JsonAsHTML(object):
    '''
    View a JSON response in your browser as HTML
    Useful for viewing stats using Django Debug Toolbar 

    This middleware should be place AFTER Django Debug Toolbar middleware   
    '''

    def process_response(self, request, response):

        #not for production or production like environment 
        if not settings.DEBUG:
            return response

        #do nothing for actual ajax requests
        if request.is_ajax():
            return response

        #only do something if this is a json response
        if "application/json" in response['Content-Type'].lower():
            title = "JSON as HTML Middleware for: %s" % request.get_full_path()
            response.content = "<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body>%s</body></html>" % (title, response.content)
            response['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        return response
```

Answer (score 3):

Django 1.10 introduced 'new style middleware': https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/#new-style-middleware

This is a new style middleware version:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse


class NonHtmlDebugToolbarMiddleware:
    """
    The Django Debug Toolbar usually only works for views that return HTML.
    This middleware wraps any non-HTML response in HTML if the request
    has a 'debug' query parameter (e.g. http://localhost/foo?debug)
    Special handling for json (pretty printing) and
    binary data (only show data length)
    """
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        if response['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
            content = response.content
            try:
                json_ = json.loads(content)
                content = json.dumps(json_, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
            except ValueError:
                pass

            response = HttpResponse('<html><body><pre>{}'
                                    '</pre></body></html>'.format(content),
                                    content_type='text/html')

        return response
```

Comment: thanks. the comment is not true though, there is no checking for query params :}

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I'm afraid that's not possible.</strike> See the accepted answer for a workable solution.

Here's why your approach did not work:

The toolbar does not kick-in because the answer [is not in HTML](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.2/tips.html#the-toolbar-isn-t-displayed). All other formats can't be "parsed" by the toolbar's middleware to include the Toolbar.

You can add your own tools to show SQL queries though. Take a look at this simple snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/161/ Or you can use a third party app for this, like [django-snippetscream](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-snippetscream).

For example, you could check if `DEBUG is True` and add this info to the "meta" object returned by Tastypie.

Also, take a look at the SQL logging in your console (runserver). Some useful resource for this: http://dabapps.com/blog/logging-sql-queries-django-13/

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/pull/253

```
pip install git+https://github.com/caktus/django-debug-toolbar@ajax-panel#egg=django-debug-toolbar
```

This will allow debug toolbar to display information about the request on the calling page.

Alternatively if you want an HTML renderer and your not too far into your project, I highly recommend **django-rest-framework**

Answer (score 1):

```
@html_decorator
def test(request):

    view = resolve("/api/v1/albumimage/like/user/%d/" % 2 )

    accept =  request.META.get("HTTP_ACCEPT")
    accept += ",application/json"
    request.META["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = accept   
    res = view.func(request, **view.kwargs)

    return HttpResponse(res._container)



def html_decorator(func):
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    wrap it inside html                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    """

    def _decorated(*args, ** kwargs):
        response = func(*args, **kwargs)

        wrapped = ("<html><body>",
                   response.content,
                   "</body></html>")

        return HttpResponse(wrapped)

    return _decorated
```

This is how I solved it.
Ok it's not automatic, but will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that by rebuilding django snippest from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/344/

```
"""
Database and request debug info for Tastypie.

Based of idea from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/344/

# settings.py:
DEBUG=True
DEBUG_SQL=True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'YOURPATH.SQLLogMiddleware.SQLLogMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
    ...)

"""

# Python
import time
import logging
import json

# Django
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connection


class SQLLogMiddleware:
    """\
    Attach debug information to result json.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.sqllog_start = time.time()

    def process_response (self, request, response):
        # request.sqllog_start is empty if an append slash redirect happened.
        debug_sql = getattr(settings, "DEBUG_SQL", False)
        if not getattr(request, 'sqllog_start', False):
            return response
        if (not request.sqllog_start) or not (settings.DEBUG and debug_sql):
            return response

        try:
            content = json.loads(response.content)
        except ValueError:
            return response
        timesql = 0.0
        for query in connection.queries:
            timesql += float(query['time'])
        seen = {}
        duplicate = 0
        for query in connection.queries:
            sql = query["sql"]
            c = seen.get(sql, 0)
            if c:
                duplicate += 1
            if c:
                query["seen"] = c + 1
            seen[sql] = c + 1

        timerequest = round(time.time() - request.sqllog_start, 3)
        queries = connection.queries

        debug = {'request_path': request.path,
                 'query_count': len(queries),
                 'duplicate_query_count': duplicate,
                 'sql_execute_time': timesql,
                 'request_execution_time': timerequest,
                 'queries': []}

        for query in queries:
            debug['queries'].append({'time': query['time'],
                                     'sql': query['sql']})

        content['debug'] = debug
        response.content = json.dumps(content)
        logging.info(debug)
        return response
```

Comment: django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware is deprecated in Django 1.6. without it no debug info is added to the response.

Answer (score 1):

With version 3.1 of the Django Debug Toolbar, there is a [History Panel](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/panels.html#history) which removes the need to wrap the JSON responses with html.